# R: How to set names in a nested list from attributes

Tags: r, list, nested, attr

Edit: I rewrite this question, as I have two related questions that maybe could be answered better together...

---

I've got some large nested `list`s with nearly the same structure and without names. All items of the `list` have `attr`ibutes and I want to assign these as names in all levels of the `list`. Furthermore I want to drop a needless list-level.

So this:

```
before <- list(list("value_1"), list(list("value_2a"), list("value_2b")), list(list("value_3a"), list("value_3b"), list("value_3c")), list("value_4"))
for(i in 1:4) attr(before[[i]], "tag") <- paste0("tag_", i)
attr(before[[2]][[1]], "code") <- "code_2a"
attr(before[[2]][[2]], "code") <- "code_2b"
attr(before[[3]][[1]], "code") <- "code_3a"
attr(before[[3]][[2]], "code") <- "code_3b"
attr(before[[3]][[3]], "code") <- "code_3c"
str(before)
## List of 4
##  $ :List of 1
##   ..$ : chr "value_1"
##   ..- attr(*, "tag")= chr "tag_1"
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : chr "value_2a"
##   .. ..- attr(*, "code")= chr "code_2a"
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : chr "value_2b"
##   .. ..- attr(*, "code")= chr "code_2b"
##   ..- attr(*, "tag")= chr "tag_2"
##  $ :List of 3
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : chr "value_3a"
##   .. ..- attr(*, "code")= chr "code_3a"
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : chr "value_3b"
##   .. ..- attr(*, "code")= chr "code_3b"
##   ..$ :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : chr "value_3c"
##   .. ..- attr(*, "code")= chr "code_3c"
##   ..- attr(*, "tag")= chr "tag_3"
##  $ :List of 1
##   ..$ : chr "value_4"
##   ..- attr(*, "tag")= chr "tag_4"
```

(Note: 1st level list items have a "tag"-attribute, 2nd level items have a "code"-attribute.)

Should be this:

```
after <- list(tag_1="value_1", tag_2=list(code_2a="value_2a", code_2b="value_2b"), tag_3=list(code_3a="value_3a", code_3b="value_3b", code_3c="value_3c"), tag_4="value_4")
str(after)
## List of 4
##  $ tag_1: chr "value_1"
##  $ tag_2:List of 2
##   ..$ code_2a: chr "value_2a"
##   ..$ code_2b: chr "value_2b"
##  $ tag_3:List of 3
##   ..$ code_3a: chr "value_3a"
##   ..$ code_3b: chr "value_3b"
##   ..$ code_3c: chr "value_3c"
##  $ tag_4: chr "value_4"
```

Since the lists are large, I want to avoid `for` loops, to get a better performance.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I completely overlooked `rapply`. Now I can work with the values in the list like: `test <- rapply(before, function(x) paste(x, "foo"), how="list")` But how to work with the attributes? Can you please give another hint.

Answer (score 2):

Got it! Three steps, but works perfectly.

```
# the ugly list
ugly_list <- list(list("value_1"), list(list("value_2a"), list("value_2b")), list(list("value_3a"), list("value_3b"), list("value_3c")), list("value_4"))
for(i in 1:4) attr(ugly_list[[i]], "tag") <- paste0("tag_", i)
attr(ugly_list[[2]][[1]], "code") <- "code_2a"
attr(ugly_list[[2]][[2]], "code") <- "code_2b"
attr(ugly_list[[3]][[1]], "code") <- "code_3a"
attr(ugly_list[[3]][[2]], "code") <- "code_3b"
attr(ugly_list[[3]][[3]], "code") <- "code_3c"

# set names for 1st level 
level_1_named <- setNames(ugly_list, sapply(ugly_list, function(x) attributes(x)$tag))

# set names for 2nd level
level_2_named <- lapply(level_1_named, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) setNames(y, attributes(y)$code)))

# clean list
clean_list <- lapply(level_2_named, function(x) unlist(x, recursive=FALSE))
```

Thanks for trying. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by recursing through the list. Try this:

```
setListNames <- function(mylist){
  # Base case: if we have a nonlist object, set name to its attribute
  if( !is.list(mylist) ){
    names( mylist ) = attr(mylist, 'code')
    return( mylist )
  }

  # lapply through all sublists and recursively call
  mylist = lapply(mylist, setListNames)

  # Return named list
  return( mylist )
}

# Test run
before_named = setListNames(before)
# Check it worked
print( names( before_named[[2]][[1]][[1]] ) )
```

Comment: As I just added to the question, I want to avoid for loops. However, did you try your code? before and before_named are equal in my test.

Comment: `identical(before, before_named)` gives me `FALSE` and the names do exist. How are the lists being constructed? Why not set the names before list creation?

Comment: I've edited the answer to use `lapply` instead of the for loop, though I doubt that would drastically improve performance.

Comment: The lists are parsed xml requested from a server. No chance to set names earlier.